# Assigning a short to int * fails

Tags: c, pointers, integer, short

I understand that I can reassign a variable to a bigger type if it fits, ad its ok to do it. For example:

```
short s = 2;
int i = s;
long l = i;
long long ll = l;
```

When I try to do it with pointers it fails and I don't understand why. I have integers that I pass as arguments to functions expecting a pointer to a long long. And it hasn't failed, yet..

The other day I was going from short to int, and something weird happens, I hope someone can I explain it to me. This would be the minimal code to reproduce.

```
short s = 2;
int* ptr_i = &s; // here ptr_i  is the pointer to s, ok , but *ptr_i   is definitely not 2
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion for why you can pass an int or  short or whatever to a function with an argument of another integer type. But integers are not pointers and they have different rules.

Comment: Data pointers are all going to be the same size.  It's the size of their targets that varies.  An `int *` and a `short *` will never be compatible if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(short)`, since it won't access the correct target size.  If your compiler warns about incompatible pointer types, you should treat it as a bug and just fix it.

Comment: But that would mean that `int *` and `long long int *` would never be compatible either but, that doesn't fail.
Thanks for the link @Shawn.

Comment: @piptin No, it would mean that they're incompatible if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(long long int)`.  But since they do have different sizes on most platforms, they probably are incompatible on yours.  Just because you don't *see* a problem doesn't mean it doesn't exist.  If you load a `long long` as an `int`, you're probably going to get the low-order (on a little-endian machine) or the high-order (on a big-endian machine).  You may not notice the difference, but it's undefined behavior.  And if you're storing to a larger size, it's even worse since you're corrupting memory.

Comment: The solution is to compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, and then fix the errors in your code.

Comment: What does "but *i is definitely not 2" mean? `i` is not a pointer. You cannot dereference it

Comment: Pointers are not integers and do not behave like integers.  The rules for pointer assignment are different from the rules for integer assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to do it with pointers it fails and I don't understand why.

A major purpose of the type system in C is to reduce programming mistakes. A default conversion may be disallowed or diagnosed because it is symptomatic of a mistake, not because the value cannot be converted.

In `int *ptr_i = &s;`, `&s` is the address of a `short`, typically a 16-bit integer. If `ptr_i` is set to point to the same memory and `*ptr_i` is used, it attempts to refer to an `int` at that address, typically a 32-bit integer. This is generally an error; loading a 32-bit integer from a place where there is a 16-bit integer, and we do not know what is beyond it, is not usually a desired operation. The C standard does not define the behavior when this is attempted.

In fact, there are multiple things that can go wrong with this:

- As described above, using `*ptr_i` when we only know there is a `short` there may produce undesired results.
- The `short` object may have alignment that is not suitable for an `int`, which can cause a problem either with the pointer conversion or with using the converted pointer.
- The C standard does not define the result of converting `short *` to `int *` except that, if it is properly aligned for `int`, the result can be converted back to `short *` to produce a value equal to the original pointer.
- Even if `short` and `int` are the same width, say 32 bits, and the alignment is good, the C standard has rules about aliasing that allow the compiler to assume that an `int *` never accesses an object that was defined as `short`. In consequence, optimization of your program may transform it in unexpected ways.

> I have integers that I pass as arguments to functions expecting a pointer to a long long.

C does allow default conversions of integers to integers that are the same width or wider, because these are not usually mistakes.